# unable to call and insert value returned by function inside trigger , is there any thing i am missing?

Tags: function, plsql, triggers

I would like to use a trigger on table which will be fired every time a row is inserted, updated, deleted. I wrote something like this: unfortunately function i am calling is not working , and it gives `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException :ora-04098 : trigger Compiere3.test01 is invalid and failed re-validation.`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test001
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON m_transaction
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   Availableqty   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Availableqty := BOMQTYAVAILABLE (:old.m_product_id, 1000000, 1000000);

   INSERT INTO MonitorTable (m_transaction_id, m_product_id, Availableqty)
        VALUES (OLD.m_transaction_id, OLD.m_product_id, Availableqty);
END;
```

Comment: Make sure your trigger `test001` is compiled without any errors.

Comment: And try executing function to test whether it returns value, something like `select BOMQTYAVAILABLE(testid, 1000000, 1000000) from dual` Thus you could make sure function does return value and that part of code is working fine.

Comment: yes function is returning correct value , but when i compile this trigger it give error on 6,3 PL/SQL SQL statement ignored and 7,34 PL/SQL: ORA-00984 Column not allowed here .

Answer (score 1):

finally i found the solution and the correct syntax is as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test001
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON m_transaction
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   Availableiqty   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Availableiqty := BOMQTYAVAILABLE (:new.m_product_id, 1000000, 1000000);

   INSERT INTO MonitorTable (m_transaction_id, m_product_id, Availableqty)
        VALUES (:new.m_transaction_id, :new.m_product_id, Availableiqty);
END;
```

Comment: i think there need to be extra columns and this possibly is wrong... see, if inserting you have to reference as :NEW values because you don't have old values on updating too because log already shot insert values and you know it you only need :NEW values but if deleted then you need to know whats been deleted referencing as :OLD so what had done in our system there is: IF INSERTING THEN insert into.. () values ('insert',:NEW....)IF updating THEN insert into.. () values ('update',:NEW....)IF deleting THEN insert into.. () values ('delete',:OLD....) something like that...

Comment: yes u r right . i am totally agree with you and thanks for the comment .

Answer (score 0):

In your column names clause, maybe Availableqty is supposed to be m_availableqty?  Based on your apparent naming convention.  It's expecting a column name and getting a variable instead.

Comment: Actually bomqtyavailable functions returns current available qty of product , i don't have any m_availableqty field in my tables .